# 2 files, match columns and subtract from 2 columns

Tags: awk

I have 2 files and I want to do some subtracting.

file 1

```
device1 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.10023 = 102030
device2 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.10026 = 1450
```

file 2

```
device1 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.10023 = 102034
device2 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.10026 = 1460
```

Desired output

```
device1 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.10023 = 4
device2 IF-MIB::ifInErrors.10026 = 10
```

Tried some awk examples and all I get is 1's

```
join file1 file2 | awk '{print $1, $7-$5}' > test
```

Comment: Are you sure you're getting `1`s? There's other issues too but the arithmetic would fail because you're mis-counting the fields (it should be `$7-$4` rather than `$7-$5`) but that would output `102034` and `1460`, it won't output `1`s. If you're getting `1`s then your real input doesn't look like the input in your question so please fix your question to state the real results you're getting or fix the example to better represent your real data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
join -t= file1 file2 | awk -F'=' '{print $1 "= " $3-$2}' > test
```

I used = as separator for both join and awk